# Does anybody knows when to use asynchronous one-shot queries with Room Android?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

*Does anybody knows when to use asynchronous one-shot queries with Room  Android?*

```
@Delete
public ListenableFuture<Integer> deleteUsers(List<User> users);
```

I am a beginner in the field, I do not know where to find this information. If anybody knows a use case, please share it with us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the UseCase interface that I use for asynchronous one-shot queries with Room:

```
interface SimpleOneShotUseCase<out Response, out Error, in UseCaseParams> : UseCase<Response, Error, UseCaseParams> {

    override suspend operator fun invoke(params: UseCaseParams): Either<Error, Response> =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        run(params = params)
    }

    suspend fun run(params: UseCaseParams): Either<Error, Response>
}

interface UseCase<out Response, out Error, in UseCaseParams> {

    suspend fun observe(params: UseCaseParams): Flow<Either<Error, Response>> = flow { emit(invoke(params)) }

    suspend operator fun invoke(params: UseCaseParams): Either<Error, Response>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we need to use asynchronous requests on all requests to database (ROOM). So we avoid blocking the UI.

For more **info**.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries